# BlocksIt.js jQuery plugin. How to attach content from url

Tags: jquery, block

I'm using [BlocksIt.js jQuery plugin](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/) I want to load content from URL when user scrolls to 90% from the top (almost bottom). How to make it load content (with class="grid") from the URL, and append everything with .grid class to '#container' block. I've already tried load(), $.get() and $.ajax(). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/almostemp/Y8Bkd/6/).

Even if it loads the content, it doesn't place it properly into the '#container' block (it pupts the content behind in the background or somewhere else). I try to call BlocksIt() function again:

```
        $('#container').BlocksIt({
            numOfCol: 5,
            offsetX: 8,
            offsetY: 8
        });
```

doesn't help.  The best I could do is (and again it won't work):

```
        link = 'http://www.inwebson.com/demo/blocksit-js/demo2/';
        $.get(link, function (data) {
            $(data).find(".grid").appendTo("#container");
        });
```

Comment: do you find solution  ? I have same problem :S

Comment: I couldn't find a solution. Just try to use another block alike script)) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying you want to append new block using blocksit

this is how I had done. It will append nicely with all your previous blocks

HTML

```
<div class="grid-layout">
    <div class="grid">content</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dynamicGrid();
});

function dynamicGrid()
{ 
    $('.grid-layout').BlocksIt({  
      numOfCol: 4,
      offsetX: 2,
      offsetY: 2,
      blockElement: '.grid',
    });        
};
```

this is how you get and append it nicely with in your grid layout

```
var url='your url to get data';

$.get( url, function(data) {
    $(".grid-layout").append(data);
    dynamicGrid();
}).fail(function(){
    alert('error');    
})
```

just place the above in whichever you want such as on click.

remember that the data return to jquery get must be in html with each content in class grid, such as

```
<div class="grid">content2</div>
<div class="grid">content3</div>
```

it will append nicely under content.